# How can I create a new vector command within a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, vector, iteration

```
for (i in 1:100) {
    e <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 100, sd = 10)
}
e
```

So I want to know how I can command (something) within each of the 20 randomly generated vectors. E.g. how can I tell it so it spits me out a new command for each new random vector?

```
for (i in 1:100) {
   e <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 100, sd = 10)
   new_vector <- mean(e) - median(e)
}
e
```

I have tried this but that's definitely not it.

Answer (score 2):

With the OP's code, we may need to initialize `e` and concatenate the object to append in each iteration

```
e <- numeric(0)
for (i in 1:100) {
  e <- c(e, rnorm(n = 20, mean = 100, sd = 10))
}
```

If we want to create a `list`

```
e <- vector('list', 100)
for(i in 1:100) {
    e[[i]] <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 100, sd = 10)
}
```

---

Or if the interest is to get a `vector` with the difference of `mean` and `median`, initialize `new_vector` of `length` 100, loop over the sequence (1:100), get the random numbers in 'e' and assign the difference of `mean`, `median` for each position of the 'new_vector' using the the sequence as index

```
new_vector <- numeric(100)
for(i in 1:100){
  e <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 100, sd = 10)
  new_vector[i] <- mean(e) - median(e)
}
```

---

Or using `lapply/sapply/replicate`

```
lapply(replicate(100, rnorm(n = 20, mean = 100, sd = 10),
  simplify = FALSE), function(x) mean(x) - median(x))
```

---

Or with vectorized functions - `colMedians` (from `matrixStats`) and `colMeans`

```
library(matrixStats)
m1 <- replicate(100, rnorm(n = 20, mean = 100, sd = 10))
colMedians(m1)- colMeans(m1)
```